# What I am doing wrong? .htaccess on subfolder

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have searched the internet and followed the steps but I can't get this to work properly.

**Step1:** Activated 'rewrite_module' in the apache menu.  After running phpinfo(), it shows that the module is infact loaded.

**Step 2:** I made changes to httpd.conf:

```
<Directory "c:/program Files/wamp/www/">
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
AllowOverride all
Order Allow,Deny
Allow from all
</Directory>
```

Here is my .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^tempor\.com/([^/]*)\.htm$ /tempor.com/index.php?page=$1 [L]
```

**Goal:** Rewrite url from 
**localhost/tempor.com/index.php?page=about** to 
**localhost/tempor.com/about.htm**

**Test result:**  Nothing happens.  The url isn't changed.  If I put some trash texts into the .htaccess, i get an error so I know that .htaccess is being loaded.

Comment: Hi Prix, sorry. I must have forgotten the .htm.  The goal is is to transform into tempor.com/about.htm.  Yes, I have tried `localhost/tempor.com/about.htm` but i got an internal server error

Comment: Yes, this returns true: `in_array('mod_rewrite', apache_get_modules());`

Comment: It is not commented on httpd.conf and there is no other rules in .htaccess.  this is all the codes.  I tried placing the .htaccess under the root (www) and also inside tempor.com but same result.

Comment: Is "tempor.com" actually part of the URI, or is that the domain or even the file path? If it's the domain or file path, you don't put it in the RewriteRule. The only stuff that goes there is what a user actually sees/types in for the URI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/tempor.com/.htaccess` code to:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /tempor.com/

# external redirection from /tempor.com/index.php?page=about to /tempor.com/about.htm
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+tempor\.com/index\.php\?page=([^&\s]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1.htm? [R=301,L]

# internal forward from /tempor.com/about.htm to /tempor.com/index.php?page=about
RewriteRule ^(.+?)\.html?$ index.php?page=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
```

Comment: Hi anubhava, I changed the .htaccess to this and put it inside the tempor.com directory but didn't work.

Comment: Can you put some garbage text on top of this file and then try to open: `localhost/tempor.com/about.htm`. See if it generates 500 error or not.

Comment: i did put garbage texts on it and i got an `internal server error`  .

Comment: ALright that verifies that .htaccess is enabled. Now can you see if `http://localhost/tempor.com/index.php?page=about` opens up properly.

Comment: yes, it opens up properly but it doesn't change the url to what the .htaccess is telling

Comment: No existing rule won't change this URL. I will add a rule for this. Can you meanwhile try to see if this URL works: `http://localhost/tempor.com/about.htm` for you.

Comment: @SaintDee: I have included an additional rule for external redirect as well in my answer.

Comment: I have changed my .htaccess but this doesn't work and it gives a 404 error.  also, the `http://localhost/tempor.com/about.htm` doesn't - 404

Comment: That is strange, `http://localhost/tempor.com/about.htm` worked for you earlier right?